# Finding correct information to update mtab and fstab?

Tags: mount, fstab

Is there an automated way to update my `mtab` and `fstab`? Or a command I can run so that I can copy the output into these files? I'm just nervous about tampering with these files because I know they are critical.

I previously had a `md0` and `md1` array but they "disappeared."   Now my `mtab` and `fstab` is stale and it is giving me problems trying to run this automatic RAID utility, [raider](https://sourceforge.net/projects/raider/).

#### fstab

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    defaults        0       0
/dev/md0       /               ext3    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/dev/md1       none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/scd0       /media/cdrom0   udf,iso9660 user,noauto     0       0
```

#### mtab

```
/dev/md0 / ext3 rw,errors=remount-ro 0 0
tmpfs /lib/init/rw tmpfs rw,nosuid,mode=0755 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev 0 0
udev /dev tmpfs rw,mode=0755 0 0
tmpfs /dev/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=620 0 0
```

#### /proc/mounts

```
rootfs / rootfs rw 0 0
none /sys sysfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
none /proc proc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
none /dev devtmpfs rw,relatime,size=1547340k,nr_inodes=215947,mode=755 0 0
none /dev/pts devpts rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000 0 0
/dev/sda1 / ext3 rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered 0 0
tmpfs /lib/init/rw tmpfs rw,nosuid,relatime,mode=755 0 0
tmpfs /dev/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime 0 0
```

### Here's what I think based on observation

#### My proposed update to fstab (should it be sda or sda1?)

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    defaults        0       0
/dev/sda1       /               ext3    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/dev/scd0       /media/cdrom0   udf,iso9660 user,noauto     0       0
```

#### My proposed update to mtab (should it be sda or sda1?)

```
/dev/sda1 / ext3 rw,errors=remount-ro 0 0
tmpfs /lib/init/rw tmpfs rw,nosuid,mode=0755 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev 0 0
udev /dev tmpfs rw,mode=0755 0 0
tmpfs /dev/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=620 0 0
```

Comment: According to this, I shouldn't edit `mtab` bt elsewhere it says I should... still confused. http://serverfault.com/questions/518967/do-i-need-to-restart-my-server-after-editing-fstab-and-mtab

Comment: sda is the whole disk, sda1 is the first partition, sda2 the second, etc. You deal with partitions in /etc/fstab.

Comment: `mtab` should not be updated. See the `mount` manual where it says "The  programs  `mount`  and  `umount`  traditionally maintained a list of currently
              mounted filesystems in the file /`etc/mtab`", i.e. the file is managed by the system.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with figuring out what happened to the RAID devices `md0` and `md1`. Did you recently updated any kernel module or the kernel itself? What is the output of following commands?

```
# cat /proc/mdstat
# mdadm --query /dev/md0
```

(Sorry, I haven't worked on RAID for quite sometime and you haven't mentioned what GNU/Linux distribution and version you are running.)